# Anime about a character that is reincarnated after 1,000 years and bathed in an elixir to make him stronger

Tags: story-identification, anime

Anime is about a male main character who is reincarnated after 1,000 years. He crosses a bridge as a test to get into a magical school. He studies and bathes in an elixir which makes him stronger.

Comment: This is a decent overview but it is quite brief. Can you remember anything else that happens in it? Why was he reincarnated? Why does he go to the school? What happens after that? Can you remember when you saw this? If you remember anything else please [edit] those details into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [*Reikenzan: Hoshikuzu-tachi no Utage*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/32094/Reikenzan__Hoshikuzu-tachi_no_Utage)? The main character is a "time travelled soul" from an earlier time period. He ages normally and then attempts to gain entry to a magic school by crossing a golden bridge.

> Long ago in the nine provinces of Kyushu, a calamitous event was
> prophesied to take place: falling comets would exhaust the spiritual
> energies of both the heavens and the lands and thus bring about an age
> of chaos upon the world. But contrary to the prophecy, the comets
> passed by with no calamity taking place. At the same time, as if
> touched by the phenomenon, a boy was born in a remote village of the
> Sokei region by the name of Ouriku.
>
> Twelve years later, as the memories of the event have faded from
> people's minds, the Reikenzan clan—one of the five supreme sects of
> the nine provinces—decides to hold an examination in order to gather
> the most talented individuals fit to become disciples and eventually
> sages. Hearing about this news, Ouriku and his servant Ouchou head
> toward the site, unaware that the organizer Oubu, despite her elegant
> appearance, is infamous for being extremely irresponsible and
> carefree; hence, making the trials in the examination unpredictable.
>
> Reikenzan: Hoshikuzu-tachi no Utage follows the story of Ouriku as he
> journeys through these trials to become a powerful sage.